# How value to __proto__ is assigned in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, proto

Recently I have been playing with javaScript prototype object and came across below example.

```
function Foo(){ 

}

Foo.prototype=null;

var fooObj=new Foo();
```

When I look at the fooObj from developer tools, the `__proto__` property points to the global Object's prototype and I can access all properties and function defined in Object's prototype object. which should point to Foo function's prototype object, since I have assigned null to it I was expecting `__proto__` will point to null, Pointing `__proto__` might make more sense but I want to understand how value  is assigned to `__proto__` after object creation? what is causing it to point Object's prototype object?

I have seen many questions on prototype and proto but none of them solves my doubts.

Comment: I suspect assigning the prototype property to `null` or `undefined` or indeed anything other than an object is treated as a special case. I know, for example, having user-land objects with a `null` `__proto__` was not possible until `Object.create` in ES5.

Answer (score 1):

Full details in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-new-operator)*, but when you use a constructor function with `null` for its `prototype` property, `new` assigns `Object.prototype` (well, the default prototype for the realm; `Object.prototype` for our purposes) as the prototype of the new object.

I believe the only way to create an object with no prototype is `Object.create(null)`.

You can *set* the prototype to `null` after creating the object via `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but in general it's best to avoid changing an object's prototype after you've created it.

---

* Specifically, it's tucked away in [`GetPrototypeFromConstructor`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-getprototypefromconstructor), which says if the type of the constructor's `prototype` property isn't Object (for this purpose, `null` is of type Null, not type Object), use the default prototype for the realm.